# If $x=\cos t,y=\cos(2t+\pi/3)$ find an analytical relation between $x$ and $y$.

Tags: trigonometry, parametric

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring this out. At the moment this is the near solution I have:

$$y=\frac12(2\cos^2 t-1)-\sqrt{3}\sin t\cos t.$$

I should be just about to solve it but find myself stuck. I appreciate any hint on how to "eliminate" that sine, or any other way in which I could express $x$ as an expression that depends on $y$. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. You have correctly used that
$$
\cos\left(2t+\frac{\pi}{3}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cos2t-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin2t
$$
so
$$
2y=2\cos^2t-1-2\sqrt{3}\sin t\cos t=2x^2-1-2x\sqrt{3}\sin t.
$$
Thus
$$
2x\sqrt{3}\sin t=2x^2-1-2y.
$$
Hence
$$
12x^2(1-x^2)=(2x^2-1-2y)^2.
$$

Comment: Yes, that step of squaring the expression! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

- To find *y* as a function of *x*, just replace *t* with $\arccos x$.
- To find *x* as a function of *y*, just take the arccos of the second expression, and try to express *t* in terms of $\arccos y$.

Comment: I committed a terrible mistake. $y$ is given by the cosine, not the sine of that expression. Sorry.

Comment: I used everything you pointed out to reach the expression I showed in the question; however that $\sin t$ is annoying.

Comment: @VladimirVargas: Sorry, I misread the question. See my new edit.

Comment: Lucian, Maybe my question is a bit misleading because I used the word function. what I'm looking for is to find an analytical relation between $x$ and $y$, such that If I plotted that relation, I would get a Lissajous figure.